# Char Followed by a char is illegal (qglobal.h)

Tags: c++, qt, typedef

I searched this forum already and found a same question but it didn't solve and not even gave any clue in solving my problem. I am doing one project in which i am using Templates. 
Firstly i used C++ map like this

```
 typedef map<int ,cal_point*> p_mMap2D;
```

and it worked perfectly. Then i tried to make a GUI using Qt, but when i used "QMap", it gave an error that

```
 typedef QMap<int ,cal_point*> p_mMap2D;
```

> Error 25  error C2632: 'char' followed by 'char' is illegal   C:\Qt
>   \4.7.4\include\QtCore\qglobal.h   897

Then i tried to use only map as i used before but still it is giving error. I searched net but didn't get any clue related to it. If i don't use Qt then its working perfectly.

Code from qtglobal.h

```
QT_BEGIN_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE
typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long ulong;
QT_END_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE
```

Comment: if yuo have defined any macros, the error is probably there. Otherwise, try to post the code from `C:\Qt \4.7.4\include\QtCore\qglobal.h`

Comment: I didn't define any macros...and the question is updated with the qtglobal.h code.

Comment: `uchar` seems to already be defined somewhere else as a `char` type. Depending on your compiler environment, this can be a case (specifically MS likes to `#define` common types like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230382.aspx). What OS/compiler are you using (I see Qt, but are you building with MinGW g++ or the VS tool chains?)

Comment: I suspect there is a `#define uchar char` somewhere before that include. Check the headers you're including before "qtglobal.h".

Comment: I am using Qt-4.7.4 and MSVS2005.

Comment: Solved it...I was including third party header file and that was the culprit. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hamid, please be good part of this community, and start selecting answer for your questions!

Answer (score 1):

Inside /src/corelib/global/qglobal.h Qt 4.8.5 contains following strings:

```
# define QT_BEGIN_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE }
# define QT_END_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE namespace QT_NAMESPACE {
```

And when preprocessor expands this macro with for example QT_NAMESPACE=qt result will be:

```
}
typedef unsigned char uchar;
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long ulong;
namespace qt {
```

Looks like an error of definition QT_BEGIN_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE and QT_END_INCLUDE_NAMESPACE.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell because you have not included the definition of `cal_point*`, but the problem is where it is defined or somewhere among those lines. Check them. It might be in an external file that makes it break, and so on.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @self: why not? If you read the comment, you can see that is where the problem happens to be.

Comment: @self: also, please leave a comment for actually trying to improve the post if you have issues with it. Otherwise, you lock your ideas out yourself to get improved.